# Retrieving based on specific condition

Tags: oracle

I have a little complex requirement on couple of tables which I am finding hard to crack.

There are 2 tables. TableA and TableB

*TableA has a structure like*:

```
-------------------------------------
ID      COL1        COL2        CAT
-------------------------------------
1       RecAA       RecAB       3
2       RecBA       RecBB       3
3       RecCA       RecCB       2
4       RecDA       RecDB       2
5       RecEA       RecEB       1
-------------------------------------
```

*TableB has a structure like*:

```
-----------------
COL3        TYPE
-----------------
RecAA       10
RecAA       11
RecAA       12
RecAB       10
RecAB       11
RecAB       12
RecAB       13
RecAB       14
RecBA       10
RecBA       11
RecBA       14
RecBA       15
RecBB       10
-----------------
```

**Requirements**:

1. Records in TableA should have CAT = 3.
2. Either COL1 or COL2 of TableA should be available in COL3 of TableB.
3. COL3 should definitely have TYPE in 10,11,12 and should have only that TYPE.

i.e *As per the above requirements*,

1. Of the records available in TableA, records with ID 1 and 2 have CAT = 3 in TableA
2. Both the records have atleast only value in COL3 of TableB. (Record with ID 1 in TableA has both COL1 and COL2 in TableB and record with ID 2 in TableA has COL1 in TableB)
3. RecAA record has Type 10,11,12 and only 10,11,12. So doesnt matter if RecAB has 10,11,12 or not. But RecBA and RecBB both does not have 10,11,12 types.

**Therefore the result should be**:

```
-------------------------------------
ID      COL1        COL2        CAT
-------------------------------------
1       RecAA       RecAB       3
-------------------------------------
```

**What I tried**:

```
WITH TEMP AS (SELECT COL3 FROM TableB GROUP BY COL3 HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE IN ('10','11','12') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0)
SELECT S.ID, S.COL1, S.COL2, S.CAT FROM TableA S
INNER JOIN TEMP T ON S.COL1 = T.COL3
WHERE S.CAT = 3;
```

Can someone please help on achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're almost there, it's just your row selection in the CTE that seems problematic, and I think you need an OR:

```
WITH TEMP AS (
  SELECT COL3 
  FROM TableB 
  GROUP BY COL3 
  HAVING SUM(POWER(2, TYPE - 10)) = 7 AND COUNT(*) = 3
)

SELECT
  S.ID, S.COL1, S.COL2, S.CAT 
FROM 
  TableA S
  INNER JOIN TEMP T ON S.COL1 = T.COL3 OR S.COL2 = T.COL3
WHERE 
  S.CAT = 3;
```

I've subtracted 10 from each of your TYPEs to turn your 10,11,12 into 0,1,2 and then used POWER to turn them into 1, 2 and 4 which uniquely sum to 7 - (in other words your 10,11,12 became `2^(10-10)`, `2^(11-10)` and `2^(12-10)` which are 1, 2 and 4.. Which must then sum to 7).

I also mandate that there be a count of 3; the only way to get to 7 with three numbers that are powers of 2 is to have 1+2+4 which guarantees that 10,11,12 are present initially. If anything was missing, extra or repeated it wouldn't be 3 numbers that sum to 7

I think RecAB is excluded because even though it has 10,11,12 it also has 13,14 which cause it to be excluded..

You also seemed to be saying that COL3 should be present in either COL1 or COL2 of table A

Comment: You're right Caius. !! That seems to be the right way. But the Type mentioned in TableB is just an example and the real values of 10,11,12 are 80000, 80001, 80002. The powers of 2 for this in going in exponent!! :( Any other solution?

Comment: Okay. I am trying without the powers. Will just compare the sums of TYPEs.

Comment: I used "minus 10" to bring 10/11/12 down to 0/1/2. Looks like you should subtract 80000 ?

Comment: There are loads of ways of pulling such a trick, it might make more sense to you to use powers of 10 rather than 2 e.g. `SUM(POWER(10, TYPE-80000)) = 111` and do it in powers of 10.. Or `CASE TYPE WHEN 80000 THEN 100 WHEN 80001 THEN 10 WHEN 80002 THEN 1 ELSE 1000 END) = 111` - this latter trick being great for stuff that isn't seqential, or alphameric etc. Basically we want to work in whole powers of something (like 2 or 10) and make sure the sum can only add up one way - there's only one way to reach 111 with these techniques (i.e. 80000/80001/80002 becomes 111.. anything else doesn't)

Comment: Thank you very much Caius !! Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use listagg analytic version to turn TYPE column into type_in_list column like below :

```sql
With temp_TableB (COL3, type_in_list) as (
  SELECT distinct COL3, listagg(TYPE, ',') within group (order by TYPE)over(partition by COL3) 
  FROM TableB
)
select tA.*
--, tb.*
from tableA tA
INNER JOIN temp_TableB tB on (tA.COL1 = tB.COL3 or tA.COL2 = tB.COL3)
Where tA.CAT = 3
AND tB.TYPE_IN_LIST = '10,11,12'
;
```